# How do I pull out data from a group of tables based on an related table value with SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a set of tables:

```
1) **nanoInst**:
rid | api_id | name | instLoc | instText | pixelPitch | logo | listImg

2) **nanoFiles**:
rid | api_id | name | fileType | fileLoc

3) **nanoInd**: 
rid | api_id | name

4) **nanoRelInd**: 
rid | inst_id | ind_id

5) **nanoGalleries**: 
rid | inst_id | file_id | gallery_order
```

My original SQL statement simple selected the the id and name from the nanoInst table, the fileLoc from nanoFiles and the name from nanoInd where nanoInst had the nanoFile id stored, and where nanoInst and nanoInd were realted a their ids.

```
SELECT 
nanoInst.rid as instID, 
nanoInst.name AS nanoName, 
nanoFiles.fileLoc AS nanoFile, 
nanoInd.name AS indName 
FROM nanoInst 
LEFT JOIN nanoFiles ON nanoInst.logo = nanoFiles.rid 
LEFT JOIN nanoRelInd ON nanoInst.rid = nanoRelInd.inst_id 
LEFT JOIN nanoInd ON nanoRelInd.ind_id = nanoInd.rid
```

I need to adjust this statement so I only get results where `nanoFiles.fileType` is 'video'. I tried simply adding `WHERE nanoFiles.fileType='video'` but 0 rows are returned but I know some exist.

--- **EDIT** ---

I've found that if I can count the number of items with videos for that row then run a WHERE clause to filter:

```
SELECT 
  nanoInst.rid as instID, 
  nanoInst.name AS nanoName, 
  nanoFiles.fileLoc AS nanoFile, 
  nanoInd.name AS indName, 
  nanoFiles.fileType as nanoType, 
  (SELECT
  COUNT(nanoGalleries.rid)
  FROM nanoGalleries
  LEFT JOIN nanoFiles ON nanoFiles.rid = nanoGalleries.file_id
  LEFT JOIN nanoInst ON nanoInst.rid = nanoGalleries.inst_id
  WHERE nanoFiles.fileType = 'video') AS vidCount
FROM 
  nanoInst 
  LEFT JOIN nanoFiles ON nanoInst.logo = nanoFiles.rid 
  LEFT JOIN nanoRelInd ON nanoInst.rid = nanoRelInd.inst_id 
  LEFT JOIN nanoInd ON nanoRelInd.ind_id = nanoInd.rid
WHERE vidCount > 0
```

The issue is `vidCount` returns the total number of videos for not just the count for that row / `nanoInst.rid`

Comment: If you run the query without the where clause how many rows do you get?  Add nanoFiles.fileType to the select list and order by nanoFiles.fileType desc and run the query and look for your 'video' value in that column.  You can also setup a fiddle at sqlfiddle.com to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Without the where clause I get all the rows expected.

Comment: and you added nanoFiles.fileType to the select and you can see that there are indeed rows with the value 'video' in that column?  The reason I ask is because if you add 'Where nanoFiles.fileType = 'video' and you get no rows, that means that there are in fact no rows that have that value for that column....

Comment: when I add that select I only get image... I know there are some associated to videos too. I need to review my statement...

Comment: My guess is that the source data is not what you think it is... are you using phpmyadmin or heidisql or some other tool?

Comment: Yeah, after review what I really need is to select everything where a video is in the galleries. I'll updated my SQL statement...

Comment: I no longer have a clear understanding of what you want, the first issue was simply that no rows existed with 'video' as a value to nanoFiles.fileType .. If you do a `select count(*) from nanoinst LEFT JOIN nanoFiles ON nanoInst.logo = nanoFiles.rid where fileType='video'` do you now get a value greater than 0?

Comment: if you could setup an sqlfiddle with some a few rows of dummy data that would help

Comment: @Logikos - every time I try to build anything i get a `Request content too large (>8000)` error even with a small amount of data in the schema

Comment: @Logikos - Basically, what I need to end up with is a table that has all the selected items where `nanoInst` has 1 or more videos. That "connection" is store in the `nanoGalleries` table. It holds the `nanoInst` id and the `nanoFile` id. The `nanoFile` table has a column that specifies "image" or "video" in the `fileType` column`

Comment: So, I could get a column that is a count of videos for the current rows  `nanoInst.rid = nanoGallaries.inst_id` and `nanoFiles.rid = nanoGalleries.file_id` where `nanoFiles.fileType = 'video'` I should get some with 0 -> n. Then I can use the overall where clause (`vidCount > 0`) leaving only the rows where the `vidCount` is greater than 0

Comment: @Logikos -  I created a sqlfiddle finally: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e318a . What I need to end up with is just the items that have a video associated with it in the `nanoGalleries`. That table hols the id for a `nanoInst` item and a `nanoFile`. If a file matches up with an `inst` that is a "video" then only is should be returned. In the link provided that would be "name 3", "name 6", and "name 8"

Answer (score 0):

The records may be getting filtered out due to no matching records in nanoRelInd or nanoInd. If that is the case, this should work.

```
SELECT 
  nanoInst.rid as instID, 
  nanoInst.name AS nanoName, 
  nanoFiles.fileLoc AS nanoFile, 
  nanoInd.name AS indName 
FROM 
  nanoInst 
  LEFT JOIN nanoFiles ON nanoInst.logo = nanoFiles.rid 
  LEFT outer JOIN nanoRelInd ON nanoInst.rid = nanoRelInd.inst_id 
  LEFT outer JOIN nanoInd ON nanoRelInd.ind_id = nanoInd.rid
WHERE 
  nanoFiles.fileType='video'
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments in your original post and the sqlfiddle you provided:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM nanogalleries
LEFT JOIN nanofiles on(nanofiles.rid=nanogalleries.file_id)
    WHERE nanofiles.filetype='video';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e318a/1/0

Updated answer based on comments

```
   SELECT nanogalleries.inst_id,
          nanoinst.name                AS nanoName,
          nanoFiles.fileLoc,
          nanoInd.name                 AS indName,
          count(nanogalleries.inst_id) AS vidCount
     FROM nanogalleries
LEFT JOIN nanofiles  ON nanofiles.rid = nanogalleries.file_id
LEFT JOIN nanoinst   ON  nanoinst.rid = nanogalleries.inst_id
LEFT JOIN nanoRelInd ON  nanoinst.rid =    nanoRelInd.inst_id
LEFT JOIN nanoInd    ON   nanoind.rid =    nanorelind.ind_id
    WHERE nanofiles.filetype = 'video'
 GROUP BY nanogalleries.inst_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e318a/50/1

Comment: Yes, but these results are missing the nanoInst.rid, nanoInst.name, nanoFiles.fileLoc, nanoInd.name. The columns I need for my results to display the needed items.

Comment: If you look at the statement here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e318a/19 you can see the vidCount column. Right now it shows all videos (5) but I'm trying to display the # of videos for that row. For this example they would all be 0 except `rid` 3 would have "1", 6 would have "1", and 8 would have "2"

Comment: based on what you did in your sqlfiddle I think i understand what you were trying to do, it can be done much easier using a group by